# ReferenceError: io3d is not defined at react npm project

Tags: archilogic, 3d.io

I tried to load scene data into aframe, then below error was showed up

```html
3dio.js:13140 Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: io3d is not defined
    at NewComponent.update (3dio.js:13140)
    at NewComponent.updateProperties (aframe-master.js:73663)
    at HTMLElement.value (aframe-master.js:72467)
    at doUpdateComponent (aframe-master.js:72441)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at HTMLElement.value (aframe-master.js:72423)
    at entityLoadCallback (aframe-master.js:72234)
    at emitLoaded (aframe-master.js:73071)
    at <anonymous>
```

```html
"dependencies": {
    "3dio": "^1.1.1",
    "aframe": "^0.6.0",
    "aframe-animation-component": "^3.2.5",
 }
```

IO3D is working at global variable, io3d is not defined.

Comment: Thanks. I created a pull request which might fix this issue: https://github.com/archilogic-com/3dio-js/pull/116

Comment: generally it's a bad idea to rely on global variables. Do you use something like webpack (i assume yes, because you are pulling 3dio from npm dependencies)? Then you should import 3dio from npm explicitly.

Comment: @macrozone fully agree on global variables being a bad idea. the IO3D (upper case) is being exposed in browser environments only for legacy reasons as window.IO3D. (We should remove it in next major version). io3d (lower case) global is only being exposed if the environment does not support CommonJS or AMD modules (i.e. script has been loaded via script tag in the browser).

Answer (score 1):

To use 3dio-js in an ES6 module you can import it like

```
import io3d from '3dio'
```